# Linux CLI command for ~"what is this machine"?

Tags: linux, command-line-interface

is there a standard command for Linux that would provide a description of the server? (Things like model, number of cores, speed...)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Not really no (in general, how do you define "description"?), but you can pull most of that info using [dmidecode](http://www.nongnu.org/dmidecode/).

Comment: That'll work for server make, model, etc.

If he just wants the type and number of cores, `$ cat /proc/cpuinfo` will do just fine.

Answer (score 6):

Ubuntu provides [lshw](http://ezix.org/project/wiki/HardwareLiSter) in `ubuntu-standard`, it will be on any distribution ending with "untu". Many other distributions have their own tools, a lot of it can be found in `/proc`. You can find the [man page for lshw here](http://linux.die.net/man/1/lshw)

Answer (score 2):

dmesg shows load of your hardware too.

Comment: If your machine has been up for a while dmesg may no longer have the boot messages. If that's a case look for a /var/log/dmesg.boot file which will have the boot messages.

Answer (score 2):

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo = CPU information
lspci = Shows PCI card Hardware name
uname -a = Shows kernel version, architecture & build date/host
cat /proc/meminfo = memory (wired + vm) info
```

These have worked on every linux system i've seen.  `lspci` is part of the `pciutils` package, and relies on a database of PCI id's.  The stuff in /proc would only be the pci id's)

Answer (score 1):

Try these:

```
# uname -a

# dmidecode

# vpddecode
```

Answer (score 0):

"dmidecode" is present in all linux distribution and usually enough, to find most relevant parts together with serialnumbers.

The standard tool in Debian and Suse however is "hwinfo". 
It is a very comprehensive  DeviceInfo-tool, and I wish (based on habbits) it would be standard accross all distributions.

For a short Overview you type

```
hwinfo --short
```

You can combine --short with specific devices like --cpu and --disk.

```
hwinfo --short --cpu --disk
```

For everything you simply type

```
hwinfo
```

Or specific to a devicetype:

```
hwinfo --netcard
```

you get a complete list of features with

```
hwinfo --help
```

In addition "smartctl --all" shows special informations about harddrives, not shown in any other tool.

Answer (score -1):

Puppet [facter](http://puppetlabs.com/facter) from PuppetLabs provides an interface to identify hardware on a system. `facter` can work without Puppet itself, can be extended to gather your own facts, and runs on many Operating Systems.

I'm using `facter`, along with Puppet and [The Foreman](http://theforeman.org/) as a Puppet ENC to keep track of hardware. Facter provides a frontend to disparate tools like `dmidecode`, `cat /proc/cpuinfo,` `MAC=ifconfig en0 |grep ether |cut -f2 -d" "`, and then information is all presented in a neat, orderly format. I've used it on RHEL, Ubuntu, Mac OS X, FreeBSD & Solaris-- gathering this information on my own was maddening. Puppet `facter` does much of the work for you.

Comment: this is not a standard Linux command

Comment: GNU/Linux doesn't provide a single, unified "standard command" to describe a server. `facter` is one of the most commonly used alternatives, however.

Comment: dmidecode comes close, and it is included in all of the distributions